# Mobile Legends takes total of 2.2 Gb in my internal storage, but I can't locate where the other 1.4 Gb is

Tags: internal-storage

Mobile Legends takes total of 2.2 Gb in my internal storage

[image]

I want to know where that 2.2 Gb is located.

I went to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mobile.legends` but only 600+ MB is in there

[image]

Went to `/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.mobile.legends` - nothing there, just a mobile legends folder that is empty.

[image]

Where is the other 1.4 GB located?

Comment: I don't know the app, so I won't write a comprehensive answer, but I suspect, it's in `/data/data/com.mobile.legends/`. All user data is usually confined to `/data/data/` unless explicitly (by the developer) written to external storage.

Comment: @GiantTree There's no /data folder inside the parent /data. All folder starts with "com." , "org." , etc. (https://i.imgur.com/MkW23Yi.png)

Comment: @yalpsid The `/data/data` folder exists on every Android folder I know. However you don't have access to list it's content. And every app has only access to it's app-specific subfolder. If you want to see the content of `/data/data` folder you must be root.